# Where is my SDK logo gone in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I Installed SDK in eclipse and I had the logo on my toolbar[image] so I could update my SDK whenever I wanted. However, I'm half way though an app and I need to update my SDK and it's nowhere to be seen on my toolbar any ideas why this is and how I can get it back
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out Windows-->Perspective -> Customize Perspective --> Android SDK and AVD Manager. Click "Yes" if you get a pop up message and then click on Android SDK and AVD Manager. That should be it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Android SDK Manager. If you just start Android, you should try Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Best way See the image [Open perspective -> For in details see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioyEI.png)

Just switch perspective to Java.